# Syntax error in Acces 2013 Query

Tags: sql

For school i have to write some queries, but this query gives me an error for some reason and i am not sure why. Even two of my teachers couldn't figure out the problem.

This is my query:

```
    SELECT Reserveringen.KlantNummer, Klanten.KlantNaam, Klanten.KlantWoonplaats, Bungalows.TypeCode
FROM Reserveringen
Inner Join Klanten on Klanten.KlantNummer = Reserveringen.KlantNummer
Inner Join Bungalows on Reserveringen.BungalowNummer = Bungalows.BungalowNummer
Where Bungalows.TypeCode = 'A1'
Order by Klanten.KlantWoonplaats asc;
```

Error:

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression
>   'Klanten.KlantNummer = Reserveringen.KlantNummer Inner Join Bungalows
>   on Reserveringen.BungalowNummer = Bungalows.BungalowNummer

If you need any more information, let me know!

Thanks in advance for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Access`, you need parenthesis if you have more than one `JOIN`.

Check out this one:

```
SELECT Reserveringen.KlantNummer, 
Klanten.KlantNaam, Klanten.KlantWoonplaats, 
Bungalows.TypeCode
FROM (Reserveringen
INNER JOIN Klanten
on Klanten.KlantNummer = Reserveringen.KlantNummer)
INNER JOIN Bungalows 
on Reserveringen.BungalowNummer = Bungalows.BungalowNummer
WHERE Bungalows.TypeCode = 'A1'
ORDER BY Klanten.KlantWoonplaats ASC;
```

Apart from that, I suggest you to use alias for longer name.

Comment: Thank you, i didn't know i had to parenthesis if i had more than one join in my query! It worked =)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way and see what happens.

```
SELECT Reserveringen.KlantNummer, 
       Klanten.KlantNaam, 
       Klanten.KlantWoonplaats, 
       Bungalows.TypeCode
  FROM Reserveringen,
       Klanten,  
       Bungalows 
Where Bungalows.TypeCode = 'A1'
  and Klanten.KlantNummer = Reserveringen.KlantNummer
  and Reserveringen.BungalowNummer = Bungalows.BungalowNummer
Order by Klanten.KlantWoonplaats asc;
```